# listings ignore final newline

Tags: beamer, listings, line-breaking

When I write listings in my LaTeX code I usually follow this format

```
\begin{lstlisting}
foo
bar
baz
\end{lstlisting}
```

and when I put this inside a normal LaTeX document, things look fine. But when I put this inside a `beamer` block, there is an extra line that is included at the end and I need to do

```
\begin{lstlisting}
foo
bar
baz\end{lstlisting}
```

to get it to look right. Is there any way to tell `listings` to ignore the final newline?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Could you provide a small (minimal) example that highlights this? Also include the versions of the files your using. Do so by adding `\listfiles` to your document preamble and including the contents *after* `*File List*` in your `.log` file.

Comment: It works for me with last beamer version and Warsaw theme. Remember that you must use `\begin{frame}[fragile]` to include verbatim code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>To remove this question from the unanswered list</sub>

Your effect can't be reproduced. The example below results in the following frame:
[image]

You can see there isn't any additional line. Please note if you use the environment `lstlisting` inside a beamer frame -- the environment `frame` needs the option `fragile`. For more information consult the [documentation of beamer](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{frame=single}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}[fragile]
  Text
  \begin{lstlisting}
  foo
  bar
  baz
  \end{lstlisting}
  Text
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```